# Regain access to running OS

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

So shortly I could kick myself, before discovering a fast RAM growing DLLHost, did (I assume) Windows decide to instead kill the Window Manager, *just* after I went to switch user into an existing session (Both sessions are logged into Administrator accounts), to pull up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and/or save the more important data in the other session.

The screen is now black, with some HDD activity, is pingable, but I hadn't changed the Windows Firewall/Services to allow what I tried to kill the process, and then presumably find a way to restart the Window Manager (RDP, [psexec like tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), or even `\\COMPUTERNAME\C$` share to be mounted with `net use`, without `Access denied` like errors, when using `COMPUTERNAME\ADMIN ACCOUNT` creds).

Trying to select one of the two users with the keyboard, entering in their password, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd>'ng to get the Security Menu, didn't make anything appear on screen either.

Can anyone think of an angle to regain some degree of access back to this machine, in order to either kill the offendeing process and/or save work I am not confident has been auto-saved (Mozilla Firefox in Private browsing mode, List of things to do in Notepad, and the like)?

****EDIT**** - I have been able to `net use \\COMPUTERNAME\IPC$ /user:ADMIN ACCOUNT`, but this didn't change the `Access Denied` output of `psexec`.

Comment: so the screen is just black right now? or does it show the log on screen?

Comment: @ShadowFrunchak - Black :(

Comment: For future reference (sorry, no suggestions for the present!) try using RUNAS, instead of switching users.  In any case, the firewall should by default allow connecting to the system from another Windows system on your local LAN, so did you try connecting to \\COMPUTERNAME\C$ with NET USE, and appropriate admin credentials?  Not sure that would help you with data that hasn't been saved in the current session, though;  the files would still have to be saved from whatever programs are modifying them.

Comment: @Debra - Thanks for the *comment* with the *suggestions*. Please see the ammendments to the question, to hopefully address most of your comments/suggestions. Though, as for what I would do once I have access, would be/have been the next hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry to say, but in the current situation you are in you will have to force kill your computer. The best way to do this would be to pull the power plug from the rear of your computer, or if your computer is plugged into a power bar, shut off the power bar.

Likely by this point, if your computer is even computing any data at all, it should have autosaved your work. If it didn't, then i am sorry to say it, but you are out of luck.

Most software has a feature of recovering the last worked on data before power loss anyways, so you are probably safe.